# Gitlab api group call is not listing all projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am writing a script to automate the production of some trigger tokens for some projects in gitlab.

The script starts with a call to the gitlab group api:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PRIVATE_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/12345 | jq > projects.txt "
```

This creates a list of projects.

Some projects are missing from this list. I know they are missing because I can see these missing projects via the gitlab web interface and they are clearly listed as part of my group (id = 12345; this is a dummy id for the purposes of this question).

Further, a call to the projects api for each specific missing project (using the same PRIVATE_TOKEN) successfully returns complete information about those projects.

Any input would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: How many projects there is in your group ? Did you check the pagination ?

Comment: Yes, that must be it - we have over 110 projects but the curl request returns 100! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [pagination with the GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination) to get complete results beyond the max page size.

Also note that if you have projects organized into subgroups, the [Group List Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects) has a `include_subgroups` option (default false) that will need to be provided if you also want to list projects contained in subgroups.